# SQL query to select only year from date in inner join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

```
table1_name "emp"  contains "hiredate" column.
table2_name "dept" contains "dname" column.
```

Below is the sql code:

```
select extract(year from e.hiredate), 
       dname 
from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno;
```

"deptno" is the common column for both the tables;

But i need only specific year(1980) to select from the date column "hiredate".

please someone help me

Answer (score 3):

You should use `WHERE`:

```
select  dname 
from emp e 
inner join dept d 
  on e.deptno=d.deptno
WHERE e.hiredate >= DATE '1980-01-01' AND e.hiredate < DATE '1981-01-01';
-- index on emp(hiredate) woould increase performance
```

Comment: do you have any other alternative query for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same `EXTRACT` in the `WHERE` clause as you use it in `SELECT`, such as

```
SQL> select extract(year from e.hiredate) yr,
  2         d.dname
  3  from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4  where extract(year from e.hiredate) = 1980;

        YR DNAME
---------- --------------
      1980 RESEARCH

SQL>
```

Comment: Without function index this expression is not SARGable